# How to delegate scroll event

Tags: jquery, scroll, event-delegation

I am aware of the fact that jquery doesn't support delegate scroll event.
So I would like to know the right way of doing it?

```
    jQuery(document).scroll(function ()
    {

    var st = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

    if (st < lastScrollTop)//if scroll up
       {
           if(jQuery('h1').isOnScreen())
           {
             console.log('I found my element');
           }
        }
   //scroll down
    else
      {
       //make an ajax call based on few conditions append elements to dom
      } 
      lastScrollTop = st;

  });
```

So,when I am scrolling down an ajax call is made and new elements are added to the DOM.However when I scroll up the new elements are not found on the current viewport but only the initial elements which were present are discovered?
So how to discover the newly added elements in the current viewport?

Edit 1:

So i have figured out the solution to the problem using two stacks

```
if (scrollUp)
{

  if(currentScrollTop < S1.peek())
  {

    if(S1.size() > 0)
     {
      S2.push(S1.pop())
      console.log("I am back");
     //change history
     }

}
else
{

    //onAjaxSuccess
    while(!S2.isEmpty())
      S1.push(S2.pop())

    S1.push(currentScrollTop);//push new 


}
```

Comment: what are you actually doing in your ajax? in this code i don't see any issue?

Comment: Idea: How about adding a unique class name to each item as you add it.  Then just do the locate on the class name?  There is also the jQuery data functions that allow you to add a unique name as a data entry or to get that data entry.  You can look for those also.

Comment: In the ajax I am fetching content for the next URL and appending to the parent container.